# What is the easiest way to get latitude and longitude?

Tags: java, blackberry, gps

I'm working on a BlackBerry app that requires getting the phones current GPS coordinates. I've tried several surprisingly complex ways of acquiring the location that have not succeeded, but I can't believe there isn't a simpler way of doing it. Can anyone tell me what the simplest way of obtaining GPS coordinates on the BlackBerry is?

Answer (score 0):

RIM has a [GPS Sample Application](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/7701/index.jsp?name=GPS%20Sample%20Application%20-%20Sample%20Application%20Overview%20-%20BlackBerry%20Java%20Development%20EnvironmentN/A&language=English&userType=21&category=Sample%20Applications&subCategory=).  And a quick Google for 'blackberry gps example' turns up [this sample](http://www.riccomini.name/Topics/Mobile/BlackBerry/BlackBerryGPS/), among many others.